# Problemas para imprimir un PDF en 000webhost

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, ya he conseguido mi proyecto de Laravel funcione en un servidor web, que es en 000webhost.
Ahora tengo un nuevo problema, que necesito imprimir documentos PDF:
Para empezar, tengo una tabla Juego con estos valores:

```
Schema::create('juegos', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('numero')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->unsignedInteger('agrupacion_id');
        $table->foreign('agrupacion_id')->references('id')->on('agrupacions');
        $table->text('materiales');
        $table->text('organizacion');
        $table->text('desarrollo');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->text('observaciones');
        $table->text('variantes');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Este es el documento PDF que se imprimira:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <font size="15" style="display: inline;">Juego Nº {{$j->numero}}: {{$j->nombre}}</font> <img style="width: 68px; height: 68px;" align="right" src="{{url($j->ruta())}}"/>
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-5 card card-1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p><b>Materiales:</b> {{$j->materiales}}</p><br>
                <p><b>Agrupación de los jugadores:</b> {{$j->agrupacion->nombre}}</p><br>
                <h3>Organización:</h3>
                <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->organizacion}}</p>

                <br><br><br>
                <h3>Desarrollo del juego</h3>
                <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->desarrollo}}</p>

                @if($j->observaciones!="*")
                    <br><br>
                    <h3>Reglas y observaciones:</h3>
                    <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->observaciones}}</p>
                @endif

                @if($j->variantes!="*")
                    <br><br>
                    <h3>Variantes:</h3>
                    <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->variantes}}</p>
                @endif

                <?php
                    $contenidos=$j->enlaces;
                ?>

                @if(count($contenidos))
                    <br><br><br>
                    <h3>Contenidos:</h3>
                    @foreach($contenidos as $contenido)
                        <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">{{$contenido->contenido->nombre}}</span>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este el controlador:

```
public function imprimir(Juego $j){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.juego', compact('j'));
        $salida=$pdf->output();
        $ruta='C:/Users/pcx/Desktop/Juego '.$j->numero.' '.$j->nombre.'.pdf';
        file_put_contents($ruta, $salida);
        return back()->with('message',['success','El PDF con los datos del juego se han creado con exito. Buscalo en tu escritorio.']);
}
```

Cuando usaba localhost, esto funcionaba bien, pero ahora me topo con este mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como se soluciona esto?
Edito: Actualmente he introducido modificaciones en confif/mail.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sendmail'),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Ahora cuando intento imprimir un PDF, sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece ser un problema del cortafuegos de mi navegador (Firefox).
¿Alguien sabe que debo hacer?

Comment: La ruta del archivo, que este en produccion (servidor) aún la sigues llamando `C:/Users/pcx/Desktop/Juego.pdf` ?

Comment: @jolsalazar Pues como se ve en el controlador si, esta es la ruta. ¿Como deberia hacerlo estando ahora en un servidor web?

Comment: @jolsalazar He editado mi problema para informar del estado actual.